# Vision API Cropping Face Landmark

Tags: android, face-detection, vision-api

I'm trying to outline the whole image with a path so I could crop it out, but the path is not following the face's outline. Here's my code :

```
 for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
                    if (face.getLandmarks().indexOf(landmark) == 0) {
                        path.moveTo(landmark.getPosition().x, landmark.getPosition().y);
                    } else {
                        path.lineTo(landmark.getPosition().x, landmark.getPosition().y);
                    }
            }
```

[image]

How do I make it so that the path only follows the outer outline of the face

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Type](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#Type) of each landmark. If you are looking at types, you will know which landmark to use next rather than whichever landmark is next in the array.